# How to expose Java-API of Scala-made jars?

Tags: java, scala, maven, clojure

I have a jar I built with Scala (using Maven). When I try to import the jar to another Java-based language as a dependency (for example, Clojure), I get an error:

```
Could not locate my/jar__init.class or my/jar.clj on classpath
```

How do I make Scala expose a Java-API for this to work?

Comment: Those look like Clojure specific stuff to me. Scala jars can be used in Java projects without a problem (some mangled class and method names aside, depending on how Java-friendly your Scala code was).

Comment: Maybe first check that it is on the classpath, as the error message indicates. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973694/how-to-add-directory-to-clojures-classpath If it is, check that it works from Java. Then it should be easy to translate it into Clojure.